# Django bulk edit form

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates

In my project I have a many-to-one relation with one Serie having up to 20 samples. I'm trying to implement a system where a user uploads a (csv)file and is then sent to a page where they can fill in any missing data. I haven't found a way to implement this and was looking for some help. The idea is that I want a table with each row having 4 fields, which are linked to the sample in question and the table will have as many rows as there were samples in the (csv)file. Furthermore, if data is already present for one of the fields, I want it to prefill the field in question. In the end, the updated data is committed by pressing a single save button at the bottom so it's supposed to be one big form.

I've added the models below. The attributes which I want to update in the form are index, pool and remarks, which may be present in the csv file already but often they aren't.
Can anyone give me any tips on how to implement this or hint at methods which are best for implementing something like this?

Models

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pool = models.ForeignKey(Pool, blank=True, null=True)
    serie = models.ForeignKey(Serie, blank=True, null = True)
    index = models.ForeignKey(Index, blank=True, null=True)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Serie(models.Model):
    a_type = models.ForeignKey(Atype)
    name = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a_type)+'-'+str(self.name)
```

Views

```
def serie_edit(request,serie_id):
    try:
        serie = Serie.objects.get(pk=serie_id)
    except Serie.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    index_list = Index.objects.all()
    sample_list = Sample.objects.filter(serie__id = serie_id)
    return render(request, 'samples/serie_edit.html', {'serie':serie, 'sample_list':sample_list, 'index_list':index_list})
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/